ReadTheDocs redirect missing versions to latest
I know there is a way to write redirect rules in project settings, but I'm not sure if what I need is possible in any way.
I just want to have a redirect that only redirects missing/unknown versions to latest. So:

myproject.readthedocs.io/en/8.1.1/ works and display 8.1.1 docs
myproject.readthedocs.io/en/8.2.0/ doesn't exist (yet) and display latest docs instead of a 404 page

Obviously, the question is about NOT hardcoding "8.2.0" or whatever version...

You can set up redirects in the RTD UI: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/redirects.html. However you will need to specify a precise regular expression pattern to avoid undesired redirection. See examples in https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-defined-redirects.html#user-defined-redirects.

I've found this workaround:
Type: Exact Redirect
From URL: /en/*
To URL: /en/latest/
Force redirect: Disabled

This will cause any nonexistent/not published version (under the /en/ directory) to redirect to /latest/ homepage, while preserving correct behavior for all versions where the page exists.
